# unable to run views written in python in couchdb futon

Tags: couchdb, couchdb-futon, couchdb-python

i started using couchdb with python-couchdb recently. The problem is when i use futon run my views written in python i get the following error message:

Error: os_process_error

{exit_status,4}

even for the default view it crashes.

def fun(doc):
  yield None, doc
i set query_server in local.ini to

[query_server] python=C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\couchpy-0.2dev-py2.7.egg\couchpy
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exit status 4 for Windows means that CouchDB is unable to open or locate file. I suppose you'd mess up [couchpy](http://code.google.com/p/couchpy/) project with [couchpy](http://pythonhosted.org/CouchDB/views.html) view server. First one is just (afaik) client library, while second one is a part of [another](http://code.google.com/p/couchdb-python/) client library that ships with view server.

UPD: For Windows Python view server install with next line according your Python path:

```
[query_servers]
python=C:\Python27\Scripts\couchpy.exe
```

Comment: thanks that worked.i messed with query_Server path,thanks again:-)